# Failed to open /etc/webmin/apache/site for writing : No space left on device

Tags: mysql, centos6, virtualmin

Im running centos 6.8 with virtualmin

My server is from kimsufi.com with a disk space of 2tb

the file system is 20gb

below I have df -h output:

```
[root@server ~]# df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G  8,7G  9,7G  48% /
devtmpfs        7,8G  176K  7,8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7,9G     0  7,9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2        20G  8,7G  9,7G  48% /
/dev/sda2        20G  8,7G  9,7G  48% /var/named/chroot/etc/named
/dev/sda2        20G  8,7G  9,7G  48% /var/named/chroot/var/named
/dev/sda2        20G  8,7G  9,7G  48% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
/dev/sda2        20G  8,7G  9,7G  48% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones
/dev/sda2        20G  8,7G  9,7G  48% /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key
/dev/sda2        20G  8,7G  9,7G  48% /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
/dev/sda2        20G  8,7G  9,7G  48% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key
/dev/sda2        20G  8,7G  9,7G  48% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key
[root@server ~]#
```

with df -i 48% is 100% Im a newbea but my server was working fine since one month ago.

I tried to clear the cache after searching google with the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/$REPONAME
```

so after running that command I logged in webmin and instead of the error in the title I got webmin screen it worked and local disk space was 50% in the panel.

after than I tried to restart mysql via /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
and mysql failed to start

Now I dont have also the mysql

the last error is `/usr/bin/mysqlshow: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

and last again `Failed to open /etc/webmin/apache/site for writing : No space left on device` messagge in webmin or virtualmin.

Guys Im very confused and afraid to lost my databases please if anyone can help me here to solve this problem will be very appreciated

edit:

```
[root@server ~]# ls -l /var/spool/postfix/
total 56
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Oct 25 04:46 active
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Oct 24 21:45 bounce
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Nov 10  2015 corrupt
drwx------  6 postfix root     4096 Oct 10 02:17 defer
drwx------  6 postfix root     4096 Oct 10 02:17 deferred
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Nov 10  2015 flush
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Nov 10  2015 hold
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Oct 25 04:46 incoming
drwx-wx---  2 postfix postdrop 4096 Oct 25 04:46 maildrop
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root    root     4096 Oct 25 08:58 pid
drwx------. 2 postfix root     4096 Oct 25 11:21 private
drwx--x---. 2 postfix postdrop 4096 Oct 25 11:21 public
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Nov 10  2015 saved
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Nov 10  2015 trace
[root@server ~]#
```

Comment: Sorry, you will have to erase the system and reinstall it from scratch, with more inodes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some program that creates a lot of very small files, in my experience on RH6 some cron script that produces output that get's sent by local mail.

Check the output of:

```
ls -l /var/spool/postfix/
```

If the number at the fifth column is high with respect to the other files that's it.

**Update**

From the output of ls -l /var/spool/postfix seems the combination cron + postfix is not the problem in this case.

At this point short of reinstalling with the option for more inodes, check if you have some place filled with files, as per this question:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117093/find-where-inodes-are-being-used#117094

Try:

find / -xdev -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n

But beware, it'll take ages. The last entry will be the directory with the more inodes inside, that should givesome clue

Comment: thanks for your reply after a hardware reboot I got apache running but after the apache restart I got also this messagge: touch: cannot touch `/var/lock/subsys/mysqld': No space left on device

Comment: [root@server ~]# ls -l /var/spool/postfix/
total 56
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Oct 25 04:46 active
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Oct 24 21:45 bounce
drwx------  2 postfix root     4096 Nov 10  2015 corrupt
drwx------  6 postfix root     4096 Oct 10 02:17 defer
drwx------  6 postfix root     4096 Oct 10 02:17 deferred
drwx------  2 p

Comment: Thanks Fredi but still having problem woth no space left and Im realy a newbea do you have any guide how to clear all caches in a centos server or webmin?

Comment: Paste it at your question, the output got cut

Comment: Fredi thankyou for your time I just deleted all files in vusrtual server domain/tmp folder and now I got webmin panel back however still confused Im sure it will be full again. the outoput got cut but Im going to edit my question right now

Comment: Just posted all output for postfix in my question

Comment: yes I was afraid and happend again again the same problem :(

Comment: Updated my answer, btw if you keep apache stopped do you have the same problem?